# Scala - Resolving Templated Type

Tags: scala

I have a templated class, and depending on the type of T, I want to print something different.

```
class Clazz[T](fn: T => String) {}
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like pattern match T (which I can't do):

```
T match {
  case x:Int => println("function from int to string")
  case _ => //... and so forth
}
```

I tried:

```
class Clazz[T](fn: T => String) {
  def resolve():String = fn match {
    case f:(Int => String) => println("function from int to string")
    case _ => //...etc.
  }
}
```

and the error message I got was that:

```
non-variable type argument Int in type pattern Int => String is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `TypeTag` so I can compare `T` to other types without losing any type info:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class Clazz[T: TypeTag](fn: T => String) {
  val resolve = typeOf[T] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => "function from Int to String"
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Byte] => ..
  }
}
```

But if I just wanted to print out something different from `toString`, I would go with a type class:

```
trait Print[T] {
  def toText(t: T): String
  def apply(t: T) = print(toText(t))
}

def print[T: Print](t: T) = implicitly[Print[T]].apply(t)

implicit object PrintInt extends Print[Int] {
  def toText(t: Int) = s"Int: $t"
}

implicit object PrintByte extends Print[Byte] {
  def toText(t: Byte) = s"Byte: $t"
}

PrintInt(3) //=> Int: 3
print(3)    //=> Int: 3
```

`3.print` is even possible if you add this:

```
implicit class Printable[T:Print](t: T) {
    def print = implicitly[Print[T]].apply(t)
}

3.print //=> Int: 3
```

Comment: Thanks. Only thing to note: Instead of "typeOf[T].tpe match", it should just be "typeOf[T] match"